# Is there way to change values in labels list from button list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem I need to change value on label with index `i` when button with index `i` is pressed. I spent long hours on this problem and I can't find a solution. Is the simplest way to write this?

```
class Page2(Page):

    opr = {"+": (lambda x,y: x+y),
                 "-": (lambda x,y: x-y)}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Prosze wybrać bilet:")
        label.pack(side="top")
        lb = tk.Label(self, text='', justify=tk.LEFT)
        lb['text'] = '\n\n'.join('{}\t  cena:\t{}zl'.format(k, d) for k, d in Tickets.ticket.items())
        lb.pack(side="left")
        
        counter_labels = self.createCounterLabels()
        plus_buttons = self.createButtons('+', 0.6,counter_labels)
        minus_buttons = self.createButtons('-', 0.7,counter_labels)

    def createCounterLabels(self):
        labels_list = []
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(Tickets.ticket)):
            labels_list.append(tk.Label(self, text=counter))
            labels_list[i].place(relx=0.8, rely=0.22 + i / 9.3)
        return labels_list

    def createButtons(self, value, relx, labels):
        buttons_list = []
        for i in range(len(Tickets.ticket)):#TODO:
            buttons_list.append(tk.Button(self, text=value,
                                          command = labels[i].configure(text=str(self.opr[value](int(labels[i].cget("text")), 1)))))

            buttons_list[i].place(relx=relx, rely=0.22 + i / 9.3)
        return buttons_list
```

Comment: Put the `labels[i].configure(text=str(self.opr[value](int(labels[i].cget("text")), 1)))` in its own function. I can't decipher it. Also you need to use a lambda there.

Comment: How to do this?  I am entry in tkinter

Comment: It's python basics. Move all of the code into its own function and then  use `command=lambda i=i: <function name>(i)`

Comment: thank you . I will try this